# Style rule working only in the styles.css and not the component css

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I'm working on an Angular 12 project with PrimeNG. I have a component on which I want to apply a rule, for exemple :

```
.p-dropdown-panel {
  width:515px;
}
```

Of course I only want to apply this rule to my component and not to every component, but when I put it in the component css, which is specified in the component.ts (cf bellow), it's not applying whereas if I put it in the styles.css it does apply. Why is that ?

It looks like this problem only occurs with classes provided by PrimeNG.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
```

A bit more details :

- I can see the rule in the head of the html in a style div, which does list the content of the test.component.css :

.btn_left[_ngcontent-njo-c121]{float:left}.btn_right[_ngcontent-njo-c121]{float:right}.p-dropdown-panel[_ngcontent-njo-c121]{width:515px}

- I do not see it in the list of rules when I select the .p-dropdown-panel div with the dev tools, only list the following rules :

  .p-dropdown-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  }

  .p-dropdown-panel {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 16%);
  }

I do import the dropdown module inside my component :

```
import { DropdownModule } from 'primeng/dropdown';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with PrimeNG however I would guess that this class is applied to one of their element inside their components.

And that's exactly the problem. Component-Styles are usually only applied inside that component. That means neither parent nor child components are (generally) affected by any styles inside them. That's called [View encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation)

You can do it by using the ::ng-deep pseudo-class however that is usually considered bad practice and deprecated. For more info see [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)

Comment: This is indeed an issue with view encapsulation, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As @berse2212 said, this is an issue with view encapsulation. PrimeNG seems to answer this problem on this page of the documentation, under Local Theming :

[https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v12-lts/#/theming:~:text=lg%22%20/%3E-,Local%20Styling,-Theming%20styles%20the](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v12-lts/#/theming:%7E:text=lg%22%20/%3E-,Local%20Styling,-Theming%20styles%20the)

I don't see ::ng-deep working on my end, so adding encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None to the @Component is what I'll do